Neo4j results to JSON in Python
While python Neo4j library, with bolt driver,  when executing queries by session.run(query) I receive a result object that can be manipulated perfectly. In the other hand Neo4j browser interface, when executing a query, in table tab, it returns a string formatted as a JSON.
Is there any function in neo4j python library that converts the results python object to a JSON string to the table in web interface?
Using .data() method over the records returns me a simple json instead a more complete one from web interface.
For example from Python .data() I receive the following dictionary (that can be later converted to json)
{'n': {'name': 'dog'}}

While the same result in web interface returns the following string
{
  "identity": 19,
  "labels": [
    "NOUN"
  ],
  "properties": {
    "name": "dog"
  },
  "elementId": "4:a94a1b6d-fb11-4844-a6e9-31362e907dd0:19"
}

As we can see the .data() from python loses a lot of information as  labels and IDs.

Assuming you are using Cypher queries, you can change your query to explicitly return the desired fields for each node or relationship.
Here is a snippet for outputting the desired fields for 2 nodes per result record:
// Get (n) and (m) nodes
.
.
.
// 
RETURN
  {identity: ID(n), labels: LABELS(n), properties: PROPERTIES(n), elementId: ELEMENTID(n)} AS n,
  {identity: ID(m), labels: LABELS(m), properties: PROPERTIES(m), elementId: ELEMENTID(m)} AS m

